# Changing the pulse colour on a CheckBox

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a simple CheckBox defined in XML like so:

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:buttonTint="@color/primary
/>
```

This will correctly tint the checkbox the primary color I define. However, when tapping on the checkbox, the 'pulse' animation color is the accent color defined in the theme, rather than the button tint color I define in the XML.

How can I set this pulse color to my preferred color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "pulse on" color and the "pulse off" color are defined by two different attributes which must be placed in the app's theme.

The "pulse on" color is defined by:

```xml
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary</item>
```

while the "pulse off" color is defined by:

```
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/error</item>
```

Note that you cannot apply these attributes directly to the element - they must be defined in your app's style in `styles.xml` and hence affect the entire application.